# Making stubs permanent on wiremock

Tags: wiremock, stubbing

I am new to wiremock and would like to create permanent custom stubs. I was able to create stubs by running a standalone wiremock instance and sending post  requests using curl commands to make the stubs. That works fine, but as soon as I restart the wiremock instance, all the stubs get lost. I was wondering if there was a way to make those stubs permanent, even after restarting the wiremock server.

When running wiremock for the first time, I tried doing record-mappings to permanently save the stubs, but that did not seem to work.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you add the stubs via curl (or the HTTP API generally), if you add a `"persistent": true` attribute to the stub JSON at the top level, WireMock will save it to disk.

Comment: When using WireMock.Net, you can use `"SaveToFile": true`. See https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net/wiki/Admin-API-Reference#post---__adminmappings